# Get the position of a string in an Array using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I want to get the position of a string in an array. For example, my XML File is `<Data>AAAA</Data>`. And, I need to get the position that defines in the variable list:

```
<xsl:variable name="array" as="element()*">
    <Item>GGGG</Item>
    <Item>DDDD</Item>
    <Item>AAAA</Item>
    <Item>UUUU</Item>
</xsl:variable>
```

Given the example XML File, the output should generate the position of 'AAAA' in the array list. So, the output should be 2. The value of `<Data>` can also be changed. Here is my sample code for getting the position.

```
<xsl:value-of select="$array[Data[position()]]"/>
```

But, I can't get the expected output. All the value in the variable item list was generated in the output.

Answer (score 1):

XSLT 2.0 provides a `index-of` function which can be used in this case to determine the position of `AAAA` in the sequence contained in variable `$array`

```
<xsl:value-of select="index-of($array, Data)" />
```

This will return a value of `3` for your input `<Data>AAAA</Data>`.